# Localising SQLite databases for Android

Tags: android, sqlite, localization

I've had a lot of people ask for my app to be translated into German. The data for my app (items and their descriptions for example) are all held in a database, and I don't know how to localise this database (which is held in the assets folder, then copied when the app first starts). There's the `android_metadata` table but I don't really understand how this works and there's not much documentation on it. How would I best go about it?

Further to this question, does anyone know of somewhere/somehow I can crowdsource the translations of this database? Whilst most crowdsourcing websites support resource files, it's more difficult to find ones which support databases.

Comment: you have to do this by yourself ... data in android_metadata it's only for internal use of sqlite fx.: for sorting order (special chars like `a,ą,b` in Polish or `a, a-umlaut, b` in German ... without localization `ą` and `a-umlaut` will be at the end not after `a`)

Comment: what u exactly want to ? according to selected locale u need to load database ?

Comment: essentially, yeah. So if someone's phone was in Spanish, it'd load the spanish version of the database, if it were in German it'd load the German etc. Unlike the resources folders, you can't put language qualifiers on the assets folder

Comment: @Espiandev: How many tables are you using? You could simply just duplicate the table(s) keeping the column names in english but call each table by a language / locale specific suffix. Example MYTABLE_EN, MYTABLE_DE and so on. You'd then just set a global string for the table name based on the locale.

Answer (score 0):

/data/data/--packagename--/databases/--dbname.sqlite

DB_PATH = "/data/data/"+ context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+ "/databases/";

im using a class extending SQLiteOpenHelper.